# Join Table in Parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am setting up a relationship in Parse using Join Table. I've looked at loads of stuff online but still don't understand. Lets take an example. Assume we have a relationship between User and Group (a user can belong to many groups and a given group can consist of many users - hence this is a many to many relationship). If I now wanted to model this in Parse as a Join Table I would obviously have a table User and a Group table. How are these linked (using pointers). Please can someone clarify? What would I need to do in the Parse data browser?